# Produce heatmap with the repeated data in pandas python

Tags: python, heatmap

I have a very large data frame, which has "SectionID", "Time" and "observed value". for which the time is repeated for section ID (Say: Daily data for one month). When I try to produce a heatmap for the observed value with Section ID and time in the x-axis and y-axis using seaborn. But, since the "Time" is repeated. I try to change the data frame to a matrix format, the error occurred "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape". I am just learning python, How can I produce a heatmap for such data, Can anybody help? I have created the sample of data below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A','A', 'A','A', 'A','A','A', 'A','A', 'A','B','B', 'B','B', 
                         'B','B','B', 'B','B', 'B','C','C', 'C','C', 'C','C','C', 
                          'C','C', 'C','D','D', 'D','D', 'D','D','D', 'D','D', 'D'],
                 'Time': [ 0, 0.25,0.5,0.75,1,0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1,0,0.25,0.5,0.75, 1,
                           0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1,0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1, 0, 0.25,0.5,0.75, 
                           1,0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1,0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1],
                 'Value': [18,17,21,14,7,7,8,7,9,11,23,5,18,17,21,14,7,7,8,7,
                          20, 22, 14, 15, 11, 17, 19, 7, 11, 16, 13, 14, 18, 20, 5, 8, 
                          4, 9,7, 12]})

 matrix_df  = df.pivot("ID","Time","Value")
 plot = sns.heatmap(matrix_df)
 plot
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `ID` and `Time` of `df` as index using

```
df.set_index(["ID","Time"], inplace = True)
```

And then you can get the heatmap using

```
sns.heatmap(df)
```

or

```
sns.heatmap(df.T)
```

for different orientation.

You get the plot as shown with ID and Time in the X-axis, and Value in the y-axis as you stated in the question.
[image]